# Selecting categories by first letter

Tags: templating, categories, array

I'm attempting to pull out a list of categories starting with certain letter(s).

What I've come up with so far seems a little excessive and I'm wondering if I've missed something obvious.

Can it all be done with just the 'craft.categories...' line?

```
{% set allCats = craft.categories.group('listingCategories').order('title').limit(null).find() %}
{% set allCatsByLetter = allCats|group('title | first') %}

{% for letter, allCats in allCatsByLetter if letter == "A" %}
    <ul>
        {% for cat in allCats %}
            <li>{{ cat.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I like this approach better then mine using search, Steve!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using the search parameter you could add it like this:

```
{% set beer = 'a' %}
{% set allCats = craft.categories.search('title:' ~ beer ~ '*').limit(null) %}
```

Comment: Upvoted for your use of 'beer'.